# To find a locus of a point P inside triangle ABC

Tags: geometry, triangles

**ABC is a triangle. P is a point inside ABC such that its distances from the sides of Triangle ABC are x, y, z. If a, b, c and k are given set of constants, prove that the locus of P such that ax+by+cz=k is either an empty set or a line segment or coincides with the sets of all points in triangle ABC**

Now, for the locus of point P to set of all points in triangle, the constants would have have to sides of the triangle and k would have to be twice the area of triangle ABC.

I can't figure anything out for the locus to be straight line however and that lead me to thinking ' What if I shouldn't be relating the distances to the area of the triangle'

One other approach I tried was to assume that locus coninciding with all points would only apply for equilateral triangles, for locus to be a straight line the triangle would have to be a isoceles and for locus to be an empty set, the triangle would be scalene one.

It would be incredibly helpful if someone could point whether I should relate the various cases of the locus to types of triangles or to given constants or to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we simplify the problem by allowing for signed distances, and consider points outside the triangle.

We will show that the set of points that satisfy $ax+by+cz=k$ is either the null set, a line or the entire plane. Then, when restricted to the (interior) of the triangle, this becomes a null set, a line segment, or the entire interior, so the result follows.

**Hint:** For a point $P$, if the side lengths of the triangle are $l_a, l_b, l_c$, then $l_a x + l_b y + l_c z = 2 \Delta $.

**Hint:** Hence, it follows that $ax+by+cz=k$ is the entire plane iff $a:b:c:k = l_a : l_b: l_c : 2 \Delta$.
If $a:b:c = l_a : l_b: l_c $, then we either get the entire plane or the null set.

Henceforth, assume $a:b:c \neq l_a : l_b: l_c $.

**Hint:** For fixed values of $a, b, c, k$, if $P_1$ and $P_2$ are distinct points that satisfy the equation, then so does the entire line segment $P_1 P_2$.

Corollary: The solution set is a (affine) sub-space. It remains to show that the solution set cannot be a single point.

**Hint:** For fixed values of $a, b, c, k$, if there is (at least) 1 point that satisfies it, then there are at least 2 distinct points that satisfy it.

Suppose we have the solution $P_1 = (x_1, y_1, z_1)$, then the point $P_2 = (x_1 + bl_c - cl_b, y_1 +cl_a - al_c, z_1 + al_b-bl_a)$ will also satisfy both equations (expand and cancel terms). These are distinct points if $a:b:c \neq l_a : l_b: l_c $.

Comment: I understand the first two hints since they are what I applied to prove that the locus can coincide with all points inside the triangle. The third hint I assumes comes from the fact that ax+by+cz is the equation of a plane and if two points lie on the plane, so must the line containing them. Is that right or is there some other reason? More importantly however, why should there be two points satisfying the equation and why should either y or z also become 0 when I plug x as 0? It would be of great help If you could further simplify the fourth point or maybe point to some resources.

Comment: 3rd hint -> If the point $P_3$ lies on $P_1 P_2$ in the ratio $m:n$, then the distances form the side can be expressed as $ (n x_1 + mx_2)/(m+n)$. This follows from similar triangles / ratio theorem. Summing gives the result

4th hint -> Hm, this needs some fixing.

Comment: 4th hint -> This should now be fixed.

Comment: Ok, I am beginning to understand the solution for proving that the locus is a line segment. I understand now that there must be two solutions. So basically it is not asked nor is it guranteed that the line segment would pass through the triangle. Or is that not the case?

Comment: And why wouldn't it be correct to say that since two planes can either intersect, be paralle or coincide with each other, the locus of point P could only be a line, a null set or the all points inside triangle ABC. I really don't know much about co-ordinate geometry so any help would be apreciated. Thanks you

Comment: 1) Yes, when the global solution is a line, we do not know if it will intersect the triangle. 2) 2nd hint shows that the locus of point P is an affine subspace of the coordinate plane, which is the null set, a point, a line, or a plane. 3rd hint shows that it's not a point. The preamble explains to consider how the A) null set B) line C) plane could intersect with a triangle, to give A) null set B) null set or line segment C) interior of triangle.

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are the lengths of the sides, and $s$ is double the area of the triangle, then
$$
\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma z=s,
\quad\text{that is:}\quad
z={s-\alpha x-\beta y\over\gamma}.
$$
Substitute that into $ax+by+cz=k$ and you'll get (in general) a linear equation in $x$, $y$, which can be shown to represent a line.

Comment: Your conclusion currently isn't true. You either get the equation of a line, or a trivial equation $0=0$ if everything cancels out (which corresponds to the entire plane), or a contradiction $0=1$ if the coefficients cancel leaving a constant term (which corresponds to the null set).

Comment: Also, you have to explain why if $(x,y,z)$ is a line in the space of "distance from the sides", then those points correspond to a line in the cartesian plane. (Vectors might make things easier here.)

Comment: @CalvinLin You are right, but I didn't want to explain all the details in my answer.

Comment: In which case, make it explicit that you didn't include all the details in your answer. The 2 points that I raised are somewhat subtle and likely to be missed at a cursory glance.